# Notepad++ find in files filter EXCLUDE

Tags: find, notepad++

I'm looking for a way to get n++'s find in files dialog to exclude certain files...

the only reference I've found so far is this http://sourceforge.net/project/shownotes.php?release_id=536795&group_id=189927 , but, unfortunately, it doesn't work.

I'm using *[^*.dll] to, I think, search for everything BUT dll files.

How can I resolve this ?

Thanks

Comment: The feature was recently implemented and hopefully the np++ guys accept it... https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/pull/4429 Add your comments and thumbs up to the pull request and maybe we can trigger some reaction...

Comment: !file.type is now an accepted exclusion pattern (space separated).

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Note, as of December 5th, 2019, Notepad++ 7.8.2 now supports exclude filters. The help documentation describes exclude filters in the [Find in Files tab](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#find-in-files-tab) section.

For example to exclude exe, zip and jar files, your 'find in files' filter will look like this;

`*.* !*.exe !*.zip !*.jar`

Relevant code change in the [GitHub commit](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/commit/dc48cee5f7f4efe1f70e7269fe5e46ac8b861b1b).

Comment: Actually `* !*.exe !*.zip !*.jar` works, too. It's different, as it'll include files without an extension as well.

Answer (score 39):

not that its a GOOD answer, but, what I've found that works is this

```
*.sql ; *.asp ; *.html ; *.as ; *.mxml
```

Its definitely not an 'exclude' list, but, by including all the types I need to look at, I get the same result.  In my case, I've only got those handfuls of types that I look for often.  If your set was wider, this would become even less useful.

Answer (score 24):

I got a tip from another forum that helped me solve this. Mark the folders you want to exclude as 'hidden'. By default the 'Find in Files' in N++ excludes hidden directories. You can then revert the hidden directories when you're done.

A little tedious, but better than nothing.

Comment: This blog https://shellcreeper.com/how-to-exclude-folders-in-notepad-search/ has a step by step solution to excluding folders by marking them hidden.

Comment: Does it hurt anything to just leave them hidden, as long as you have Windows Explorer set up to show hidden directories? It took a few minutes to mark everything in my .hg folder as hidden. My search crashed the first time after I did it but worked fine after that.

Comment: In my case, marking my node_modules folder "Hidden" takes about 3 minutes from File Explorer. Any way to speed this up?

Comment: @Noumenon just change the top level directories to hidden status. Notepad++ will skip the child directories in a hidden folder.

Answer (score 22):

Perhaps the real answer is don't use NP++ for this. Have you looked at http://www.wingrep.com/features.htm or

Edit: I use https://tools.stefankueng.com/grepWin.html these days

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

For me - finding this page, reading the answers, reading the features.htm in this answer, downloading the software from sourceforge, installing it, and searching for my thing --- **finished before the Notepad++ search I started before even going to sourceforge finished**.

Comment: Disagree.  The point was that I am already using Npp to do other tasks in a project.  I didn't wish to leave the tool to do a job that could be made easier by a slightly better filter engine.  I recognize, though, that others may not have the same constraints :D

Comment: with grepwin, in the text match, type -*.dll to exclude dll files

Answer (score 22):

There may be a more elegant way, but you could use PowerShell to get all of the extensions in a folder, and then just remove the ones you don't want. This example gets all of the extensions in the "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer" folder.

NB: don't forget to surround (Get-ChildItem ... -join ";*" with parentheses.

```
"*" + ((Get-ChildItem -File -recurse "C:\Users\SomeUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsService1" | Where {$_.Extension -ne ""}| Select-Object Extension -unique | Sort-Object Extension | Get-Unique -asString  | Select -ExpandProperty Extension | % { $_.ToLower() } | Get-Unique) -join ";*")
```

This returns:

> *.cache;*.config;*.cs;*.csproj;*.exe;*.jmconfig;*.manifest;*.settings;*.sln;*.txt

Then just remove what you don't want.

Comment: `*.bin;*.bmp;*.buildinfo;*.bz2;*.cnf;*.conf;*.conv;*.csm;*.css;*.csv;*.da;*.dat;*.de;*.dic;*.dist;*.doctree;*.dtd;*.en;*.ent;*.eot;*.err;*.es;*.euc-kr;*.exp;*.file;*.fr;*.frm;*.gif;*.gitignore;*.gz;*.h;*.hhvm;*.htaccess;*.html;*.icc;*.ico;*.inc;*.ini;*.ini-development;*.ini-production;*.inv;*.jpg;*.js;*.jshintrc;*.json;*.koi8-;*.lang;*.lib;*.log;*.map;*.md;*.mediawiki;*.mo;*.myd;*.myi;*.new;*.nocoverage;*.ods;*.opt;*.pdb;*.phar;*.php;*.phtml;*.pickle;*.pid;*.pl;*.png;*.properties;*.pt-br;*.py;*.rst;*.sh;*.so;*.sql;*.sty;*.svg;*.sys;*.tpl;*.trg;*.trn;*.ttf;*.txt;*.types;*.utf8;*.var;*.woff;`...

Comment: /\ The above is *not* comprehensive, I had to cut it due to the character limit for comments in this site. Too bad the char limit for Notepad++ "Filters" is even lower, at precisely 255. So, a "negation" filter would indeed be nice.

Comment: I had to search in files on a W2K3 server, so no powershell, but I ran this script on a Windows 10 PC using a share folder for the W2K3 server and it worked perfectly.  Have an upvote.

Answer (score 8):

Please note tested with Notepad++ v7.8.7

as n00b has answered

This works:

`*.* !*.obj`

But this does not work!: `*.*;!*.obj`  => searches no files!

on the other hand this does work
`*.*; !*.obj`

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and found a 3-step solution:

1. Search in all files
2. Copy the result as text in a new Notepad++ tab
3. Use a regular expression to remove all entries that do not interest you

Here is my RegEx (the two spaces at the start are relevant):

```
  M:\\.+?\\([^\\]+\.(csproj|dll)|packages\.config|Build\.props) \(\d+ hits?\)([\r\n]+\t.+)+[\r\n]+
```

All my results where on M:, you will have to adapt the start to what fits your results. If you run a "Replace all" with an empty string it removes all results in files ending with "csproj" or "dll", and also in the files "packages.config" and "Build.props".

Comment: There are some downsides to this approach. One is that not skipping files can add considerable time to the search. Another one is that, as of 3/2021, some binary files can crash Notepad++ search.

Answer (score -1):

The solution from https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/10653/exclude-directories-from-the-search/5 is to temporarily set those folders you want to exclude to be 'hidden' folders (hiding just the top level sub-dir is sufficient), and this then stops Notepad++ descending into that sub-directory.

Worked for me just now!