# How do I exclude a list of folders in Search in Notepad++

Tags: search, syntax, notepad++

I have searched online and have not yet found a direct stack where someone is saying this is an example of all common folders of 2020 to ignore, that unofficial list would also be a nice edition to this post. I will add some:

bin
node_modules
dist

Please add the remaining and what to enter as a string here with correct syntax, example correct the below string question:
[image]

Comment: Example: I'm often doing a search on a project where there are unknown file types where only certain auto-generated folder directories need to be ignored. I however, do not agree with the 'trick' make folder hidden, I follow the 'should not have to tamper with folders' motto.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notepad++ find in files filter EXCLUDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198829/notepad-find-in-files-filter-exclude)

Comment: No not at all. Did you even read the question?

Comment: That is a most unhelpful comment. Of course I read the question and I provided a link to the question that I believe comes close to providing an answer to your question. The question itself is confusing, for example what are *"bin node_modules dist"*? To the best of my recollection, none of the many Windows systems I have used have had such folders. Further you have not stated where in the folder hierarchy you are expecting those files.

Comment: Anyone mind reposting the same screenshot with the correct Filters:? That's all that I was ever asking for, is a working example including the three folders that I have mentioned.

Comment: The Notepad++ manual pages about [find in files](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#find-in-files) show what is possible. As I read it, it provides include and exclude filtering based on file extension, plus the directory field allow one entry which is the root for the search. [This page](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15741/faq-desk-feature-request-or-bug-report) explains how to request a new Notepad++ feature.

Answer (score 36):

This is a feature added to [v8.2](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/v8.2/): "Add exclude folder(s) ability in Find in Files".
In the application, hover your cursor over the "Filters" label in the "Find in Files" dialog to see usage examples, including these relevant ones:

> Find in all files but exclude folders test, bin & bin64:
> `*.* !\tests !\bin*`
>
> Find in all files but exclude all folders log or logs recursively:
> `*.* !+\log*`

To accomplish what you're describing, you could try:

```
*.* !\node_modules !\bin !\dist
```

Or, to exclude those folders recursively:

```
*.* !+\node_modules !+\bin !+\dist
```

I find this to be useful:

```
*.* !+\node_modules !+\bin !+\obj !+\lib !+\packages
```

Comment: Documentation: https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#find-in-files-tab

Comment: @JustinStolle how to exclude folder with space in folder name?

Comment: @Grace Unsure if there's a better way, but you could use `*.* !+\exclude?this` as your filter to recursively exclude searching a folder named "exclude this". It will also, however, exclude other folders with a single character in between the words, such as "exclude-this".

Comment: A question mark `?` works as a single-character wildcard while an asterisk `*` can represent 0 or more characters.

Comment: Thanks for including the minimum version number.  I couldn't work out why it wasn't working then I realised I was on Notepad++ version 7.

Answer (score 14):

From what I can tell, exclusion of directories (in the **Filters** field, at least) isn't supported in Notepad++ (as of early 2021).

There's a silly hack where you add the *HIDDEN* attribute to a directory using **File Explorer**, then ensure the **In hidden folders** checkbox in the **Find in Files** dialog is unchecked.

The directories I usually want to exclude contain binaries that sometimes cause Notepad++ to crash during a **Find in Files...**. Best I've been able to do is to include a long list of exclusions, e.g.:

```
*.* !*.a !*.bak !*.bin !*.bmp !*.cache !*.cur !*.db !*.db-shm !*.db-wal !*.dll !*.dmp !*.DS_Store !*.exe !*.exp !*.icns !*.ico !*.ide !*.ide-wal !*.idx !*.iobj !*.ipch !*.ipdb !*.jar !*.lib !*.lock !*.log !*.mdb !*.mp4 !*.msi !*.nib !*.nupkg !*.o !*.obj !*.opendb !*.out !*.p7s !*.pack !*.pch !*.pchast !*.pcm !*.pdb !*.png !*.res !*.ser !*.so !*.sqlite !*.suo !*.sym !*.tif !*.tiff !*.tlog !*.user !*.winmd !*.xcuserstate !*.xls !*.xpm
```

Your list will likely be different, of course. Note that the inclusion(s) go *first*, followed by the exclusions.

I saw a post that claimed that the contents of the **Filters** field was limited to 255 characters. I haven't checked to verify whether that's (still) true, but it's something to watch out for.