# Compact syntax to exclude file extensions from search

Tags: regex, find, notepad++

Basically I wonder if there's a shorter way to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59419084/10133797):

```
*.* !*.exe !*.zip !*.jar
```

Problem is, I write software that generates files with extensions I can't predict - neither in what I want to exclude, nor include, so my only option is to append exclusions as I go. But my list's length now exceeds N++'s limit, so I wonder if it can be shorter, like

```
*.* !*.[exe zip jar]
```

Comment: Why not writting a script in your favorite scripting language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[No](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#find-in-files-tab):

> The Filters list is a space-separated list of wildcard expressions that cmd.exe can understand, like `*.doc foo.*`.
>
> - Wildcards can include `*` for zero or more of any character, and `?` for exactly one of any character.
> - Most characters work as literals. However, space is used as the separator, and thus cannot be used as a literal in your filter. Some punctuation characters have special meanings (like the `?` and `*` wildcards, or the `!` exclusion or `!+\` for recursive exclusion), and cannot be used as literals. Also, the `;` causes problems, so even though Microsoft allows it in file and path names, using a `;` in the Filters box will not work as you might hope. If you want to match a space or a semicolon `;` or other problematic-punctuation in your file or folder for your Filter (whether for inclusion or exclusion), then use the `*` and/or `?` wildcards instead. (So `x?y.txt` will match the file `x;y.txt` or `x y.txt` (with a space between `x` and `y`).) And sorry, no, you cannot use quotes around a path-with-spaces to allow the spaces to work as literals: the space is a separator in this field.

That's because it's simply not a regular expression. Just like the command line/prompt only knows wildcards, not regular expressions, and also no mix of both (f.e. using square brackets). Likewise "*Directory*" cannot be used with a regex either.